# My first nested for loop

Tags: c++

I am trying out my first nested for loop and I can't seem to see the problem.  As the code is written, all 9 values come out as the number '9'.  I want them to be 1 through 9.

```
int arraySize = 9;
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < (arraySize + 1); j++)
    {
        gameBoard[i] = j;
    }
}
```

Been looking at this too long - I am sure the solution is obvious...  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why do you think you need a nested for-loop to fill in a one-dimensional array?

Comment: Just use one for loop, as you are using single dimensional array, `for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++){ gameBoard[i] = i+1; }`

Comment: @Jongware - because I have only been using C++ for a couple weeks and I know basically nothing!  But now I know this - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your outer loop goes through each slot in the array.
- Your inner loop assigns 1 through 9 to current slot of the array.
- Since the last assignment of your inner loop is 9, you have an array full of 9s.

You don't need nested loops for this. As Log1c mentioned above, you can do this with a single loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    gameBoard[i] = i + 1;
}
```